# 1941-1945 — Великая Отечественная война. Подлежащее и сказуемое

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> 1941-1945 — Великая Отечественная война.

Временные границы здесь можно считать подлежащим, а *Великая Отечественная война* — сказуемым?

Answer (score 1):

Не стоит забывать, что предложение может не иметь сказуемого вообще, а иметь  только подлежащее. Здесь подлежащее - слова `война`:

> 1941-1945 — Великая Отечественная **война**.

Почему прилагательные (Великая Отечественная) не являются сказуемыми?
Убедиться в этом нам поможет....

> тире

А оно-то здесь при чём? А при том, что оно заменяет в данном случае сказуемое. Ведь предложение можно переделать так:

> В 1941-1945 **шла** Великая Отечественная **война**.

И тогда появиться сказуемое. Но если вы сказуемое убираете, то нужно ставить тире:

> 1941-1945 **—** Великая Отечественная война.

Answer (score 0):

Можно интерпретировать "1941-1945" как именительный темы. Или все предложение - неполное с пропуском слов "в эти годы была"."